# Question about function with Lipschitz derivative

Tags: analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I cannot solve the following problem:

> Show that $$\left|\int_a^bf(u)\,du-f(a)(b-a)-\frac{1}{2}f'(a)(b-a)^2\right|\le\frac{C}{2}|b-a|^{2+\delta},$$ where $0\le a\le b \le 1$, $f$ is continuous, $f'$ is Lipschitz of order $\delta$ on $[0,1]$ and $C$ is the Lipschitz constant.

The only result I've got so far is that
$$\left|\int_a^bf(u)\,du-f(a)(b-a)\right|\le\frac{C}{2}|b-a|^{2},$$
and I have no idea how to prove the initial problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Taylor's Theorem with the remainder term (or by the mean value theorem):
$$ f(u) = f(a) + (u-a) f'(\xi(u)) ,$$
where $a \le \xi(u) \le u$.  Hence
$$ f(u) - f(a) - (u-a) f'(a) = (u-a) (f'(\xi(u)) - f'(a))  \tag 1.$$
Also
$$ |f'(\xi(u)) - f'(a)| \le C |\xi(u) - a|^\delta \le C |b-a|^\delta .$$
Now integrate both sides of (1) with respect to $u$ from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: You are missing a $'$ on the RHS of $(1)$ and on the LHS of the last line. Very nice, btw!